# Is there hotkey for Show Desktop Icons function in Windows?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, icons, hotkeys, desktop-customization

On my desktop there are a sea of icons and I realy like ability to hide them.
I can do that if do right click on desktop and find arrange icons -> Show Desktop Icons
I am also addicted to many types of keyboards shortcuts and I use mouse just when I have to.
Is there hot-key for function I mentioned already.  My OS is WIN XP and I do not know is this function relater to my Nvidia display adapter drivers.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a shortcut to the [HideDesktopIcons.exe](http://www.howtogeek.com/geekers/HideDesktopIcons.zip) application.
2. Edit the properties of the shortcut to give it a hotkey.

— [How-To Geek - Create a Shortcut or Hotkey to Turn the Desktop Icons On or Off](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-a-shortcut-or-hotkey-to-turn-the-desktop-icons-on-or-off/)

Comment: Thanx that was fast, and great I hope so that this hideDesktopIcons.exe is safe and do not taking extra resources on com when it is running

Comment: @adopilot: VirusTotal result: http://www.virustotal.com/file-scan/report.html?id=ffb0cdb9c7fa8f9700a18be4f2633eb3f76f70355d7a06898fb62544ce624840-1292680104

Answer (score 1):

1. Download **Actual Hide Desktop Icons**: [Click here](http://actualtools.com/hfiles/hidden/ActualHideDesktopIcons.zip)
2. Extract the zip file & create a shortcut from ActualHideDesktopIcons.exe
3. Place the shortcut anywhere for your convenience & use it to toggle hide/show desktop icons.

   - If you’re really interested in **creating a keyboard shortcut** to show or hide desktop icons with the help of **AutoHotKey**. => Continue to the source tutorial. *(I've tried a simple solution such as assigning a shortcut key to the created app shortcut via its Properties, but it doesn't work well after a few usages.)*

Source: [How To Create Keyboard Shortcut To Show or Hide Desktop Icons](https://www.intowindows.com/keyboard-shortcut-to-show-or-hide-desktop-icons/)

---

Why not using **HideDesktopIcons.exe** from How-To-Geek article?

HideDesktopIcons program works ok but was not perfectly programmed. It can toggle show/hide Desktop icons normally, but it doesn't update the state of Show desktop icons in the context menu. So, sometimes it seems broken due to conflicting the state with our old usage behavior. **(Right-click > View > Show desktop icons)**