# How to toggle desktop icons' visibility in Windows 7 or 8

Tags: windows-7, desktop

I want to create a taskbar icon which toggles the visibility of the desktop icons. If I click it while desktop icons are shown, they must disappear. If I click it while they are hidden, they must appear.

I think there is a way to do this using commands written in plain text form. Any help is appreciated

Comment: I think your confused with the "Show Desktop"-shortcut. This will show the desktop when you have Windows open. The Hide/Show Desktop icons can't be toggled with a simple notepad/test-file. You can follow the instructions in [this topic](http://superuser.com/questions/238089/is-there-hotkey-for-show-desktop-icons-function-in-windows) so this would actually a duplicate question of that. (There is [a way](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/83890-45-shortcut-hiding-unhiding-desktop-icons) to hide the icons with a registry-file (`.reg`) but that's not a toggle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think there is a way to do that using commands written in notepads

You can write C and C++ using Notepad.

[`SHGetSetSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762200.aspx)  takes a pointer to a [`SHELLSTATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759788.aspx) structure. `SHELLSTATE` has a `fHideIcons` member:

> `fHideIcons`
>
> Type: BOOL
>
> TRUE to hide desktop icons, FALSE to show them.